# Avoid 302 Redirects through Apache

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-proxy, confluence, ajp

Hello
I have a confluence installation running on tomcat. In front of tomcat I have an apache server.

When I go to my page a 302 to /homepage.action is done and afterwards a redirect to the start space set in confluence and then a third redirect to actual start page of this page.

This is annoying and I don't know how the google bot is affected by it.

Thus I have two questions:

1. How is the google bot affected by
   all this redirects?
2. How can I avoid these redirects with apache?

I tried to make a proxy directive directly to my landing page.

```
<LocationMatch ^/$>
    ProxyPass ajp://myurl:8009/mysite
    ....
</LocationMatch>
<LocationMatch /*>
    ProxyPass ajp://myurl:8009/
    ....
</LocationMatch>
```

But this does not work. Either I get a 404 or I get to every request the same response.

Currently I got this configuration working:

```
<LocationMatch />
    ProxyPass ajp://myurl:8009/
    ....
</LocationMatch>
```

But this leads to a not so cool URL at the starting page.

Kind regards

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atlassian has [documented](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Using+Apache+with+mod_proxy) this use case.

**UPDATE 4/20/2011**

Well, I tried `mod_proxy` with Confluence and, like you, didn't like the results. I found using `mod_jk` to be simpler and cleaner (which I think is your objective here with the friendly URLs).

Again, Atlassian has [documented](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Using+Apache+with+mod_jk) how to use mod_jk. Here are my configs:

*[confluence-install]/conf/server.xml*

```
<Connector port="8016"
              enableLookups="false" protocol="AJP/1.3" minSpareThreads="5" maxThreads="256" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

*[/etc/apache2/workers.properties]*

```
worker.list=confluence
worker.confluence.host=localhost
worker.confluence.port=8016
worker.confluence.type=ajp13
```

*[/etc/apache2/httpd.conf]*

```
NameVirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName confluence.domain.com

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/confluence-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/confluence-access.log combined

        JkMount / confluence
        JkMount /* confluence

        JkLogLevel warn
        JkLogFile /var/log/apache2/confluence_jk.log

</VirtualHost>
```

Hopefully, switching to `mod_jk` is an option for you. I hope this helps resolve your question.

Comment: Ehm, yes, and where exactly in this document is an answer to my question? I have of course read this article before I posted my question on stackoverflow. First, everything described in this document I have already mentioned in my question. Second, this document is only a standard description of configuring ajp with tomcat and apache. I wanted a cool URL for my landing page and avoid 3 unneccessary redirects. Sry, but this is not helpful.